# Membership Payment

Tags: civimember, payment

I am looking into using CiviCRM for my organization, which matches babysitters and pet-sitters to healthcare workers. I noticed that members must pay to use CiviCRM. I am wondering whether our clients (healthcare workers) would need to sign up and pay for a membership if we were use to use CiviCRM for our organization. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use CiviCRM without using the Membership module at all, or you can add free Memberships.

That said, I may be mis-reading your comment. CiviCRM is free open source software, so there is no 'you must pay to use civicrm' but there are often costs associated with 'freedom' namely hosting, specialist configuration, etc but there is no 'user fee' per se for CiviCRM. Sorry if i am misunderstanding.